# Google Apps script error for Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Receiving this error

Script function not found: myFunction

Debugging etc

```
    function assignEditUrls() {
       var form = FormApp.openById('1idgfcX7LYUssTzwnR2MnNDWnXXIkMY0u6xrvBVv0oQ4'); 
    }
```

I want to re-direct a specific Google form URL to another form upon the opening of the form

Comment: You need to run the function assignEditUrls() and not the function myFunction()

Comment: If `myFunction` is not found, then it may be that you haven't yet saved the code page in the Script editor. Then, as @Kevkeev13 says, run `assignEditUrls()`.